# Strange eigenvalues question, from considering a quadratic form,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $n$ be an integer greater than 1, $\alpha$ be a real number, and consider the quadratic form $Q_{\alpha}$ given by:

for every $(x_1, ... , x_n) \in R^n$,

$$Q_{\alpha}(x_1,...,x_n)= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \alpha(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2$$

Find all the eigenvalues of $Q_{\alpha}$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $n$.  What is the condition on $\alpha$ for $Q_{\alpha}$ to be positive-definite?

EDIT: I am currently expanding out every term, and then regrouping the common $x_ix_j$ terms to see what I can come up with and to see whether I can spot a matrix that I can put together...

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint. Let $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$ and let $e$ denote the $n$-vector of all ones. Then

$$
Q_\alpha(x) = x^Tx - \alpha (x^Te)(e^Tx) = x^T(I - \alpha ee^T)x
$$

So you need to find the eigenvalues of the matrix $A_\alpha = I - \alpha ee^T$.

Comment: Very cool and pretty technique to find the matrix without brute force, @K.Miller.  Hmm...so the matrix $I - \alpha ee^t$ has entries $(1-\alpha)$ along the diagonal, while all other entries are $-\alpha$.  Then the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $det(I - \alpha e e^t - \lambda I)$ ...

Comment: Here is another hint. Try to determine for what values of $\alpha$, if any, $A_\alpha$ has a zero eigenvalue. You will also need to determine the geometric multiplicities of any eigenvalues you find.

Comment: Hi @K.Miller, looking at the matrix, the case when $\alpha = 0$ gives the Identity matrix, and an eigenvalue is 1, with geometric and algebraic multiplicity = n ...hmm....

Comment: I am currently trying to manipulate the input in $det(I-\alpha e e^t - \lambda I)$ to see whether I can get a product of matrices, and then split off the determinant, using the multiplicative property.  And then since the determinant is the product of eigenvalues, I wonder whether I can say something from here... @K.Miller,

Comment: Just took a short break and realized that this might be a special matrix that I've seen before:  it has constant diagonals from left to right...which I believe is called a "circulant matrix".  I'm sure that I can look up the formula for it on Wikipedia, @K.Miller, but I would much rather solve this with fundamentals than appealing to a formula that I would likely forget.  What do you think?  Can you offer another hint?  :-)

Comment: Look for nontrivial solutions of $A_\alpha u = 0$.

Comment: @User001 Another hint: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, then $1-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $I-B$. In this case, the matrix $B$ has a very simple structure that should allow you to determine its eigenvalues more or less by inspection. Remember that the eigenvectors of a linear transformation represent lines that are mapped to themselves.

Comment: Hi @amd, letting $B$ = $I- \alpha ee^t$, then the matrix $I-B$ is a matrix that has, in every entry, $+\alpha$, and this matrix has eigenvalues $1-\lambda$.  Where can I go from here?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 Set $B=\alpha ee^T$, the matrix with all entries $\alpha$ instead. What are the eigenvalues of this matrix? You should be able to determine one of them immediately, and a little thought about the linear transformation that $B$ represents should give you the others. Once you have them, the eigenvalues of $I-B$ follow.

Comment: Ooh! @amd! I used a sample vector (1,1,...,1), and it is an eigenvector, with eigenvalue $n\alpha$ :-)  Hmmmm...now the other eigenvalues...

Comment: ..."in terms of $\alpha$ and $n$" ... that makes sense now!  :-) hmmm...need the rest of the eigenvalues @amd ...

Comment: Hi @amd, I think that this is the only non-zero eigenvalue of $B$.  If $\alpha =0$, the matrix has all zeroes, and a zero eigenvalue of multiplicity = $n$.  So, in total, the eigenvalues of $(I-B)$ are $\lambda_1 = (1-n\alpha)$ and $\lambda_2 = (1-0) = 1$.  What do you think, @amd?  Thanks,

Comment: And for positive-definiteness, @amd, since $n$ is an integer greater than $1$, then we simply require that $0< \alpha < \frac{1}{n}$.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 Looks good to me. Note that all eigenvalues of $B$ must be real because it’s symmetric, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ because it’s singular, and it can only have one other eigenvalue because its image is the line $\operatorname{span}\{(1,\dots,1)^T\}$ (with eigenvectors $k(1,\dots,1)^T$).

Comment: Ooh, yes, it must have a zero eigenvalue, since it has non-trivial null-space - the eigenspace for eigenvalue 0.    Thanks so much for your cool hints, @amd!  Have a great night :-)

Answer (score 1):

For constant $S = \sum x_i$, the sum of squares is minimum when all $x_i$ are equal, at which point the form equals the rank 1 quadratic form $n(S/n)^2 - \alpha S^2 = S^2 (\frac{1}{n} - \alpha)$.

Hence definiteness requires $\alpha \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Subtracting the rank 1 form from $Q$ leaves the variance-like form $\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2$ where $\bar{x}=S/n$.  That is a decomposition of $Q$ as a sum of $n+1$ squares

$$ Q_{\alpha} = \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + ( \frac{1}{n} - \alpha) (\sum_i x_i)^2 $$

The other part is essentially the calculation of eigenvalues of the all-1's matrix, one of the more frequently asked questions on the site.

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22all+ones%22+matrix